# C# WPF MVVM - textbox in system-tray icon contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, keydown, system-tray

I'm currently tring to use a textbox in the contextmenu of my system-tray icon.
The problem is, that the textbox doesn't react on the keydown event. that means I'm not able to insert text into my textbox.

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="NotifyIcon" ToolTip="App" IconSource="/Images/MyIcon.ico" >  
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>  
        <ContextMenu MaxWidth="180">  
            <MenuItem Width="auto" Header="Template">  
                <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>  
                        <StackPanel Width="auto" Height="auto" Orientation="Horizontal" >  
                            <TextBox Height="20" Text="{Binding Initial.textBoxText, Source={StaticResource Locator}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                 Name="txtNumberFromTrail" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="105" >  
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>  
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">  
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Initial.KeyDown, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                                                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />  
                                    </i:EventTrigger>  
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </TextBox>  
                        </StackPanel>  
                    </DataTemplate>  
                </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>  
            </MenuItem>  
        </ContextMenu>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>  
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

Comment: Which keys do you want to record? Normal text keys or special keys (eg. arrow keys)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "Initial" is a property in ViewModelLocator (Locator) which returns a reference of the viewmodel, here is how you would define the command in the viewmodel:

```
    private RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> _KeyDown;
    public RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> KeyDown
    {
        get
        {
            if (_KeyDown == null)
            {
                _KeyDown = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(delegate(KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    //Functionality that you need to perform on this event    
                });
            }
            return _KeyDown;
        }
    }
```

Your XAML appears fine to me. If you define the command as above, hopefully it would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having difficulties to focus textbox it is because you are not activating the window thread that the textbox control belongs to. Check the code below. Happy coding.

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

and...

```
tb.ShowCustomBalloon((UIElement)balloon, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PopupAnimation.Scroll, null);

HwndSource source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(balloon);
IntPtr handle = source.Handle;

SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```